# Parse Notification issue. iOS 9.1, Xcode 7.1.1

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I followed the instructions at:
https://www.parse.com/apps/quickstart?onboard=#parse_push/ios/swift/existing

[image: Error message]

I am testing my application as independent developer on my own iPhone (5s), which is running the latest iOS operative system.

I use Swift 2.0 as programming language and I have not found any useful troubleshooting guide.

Any tutorial or helpful link is more than welcome.

Comment: Read the iOS guide instead on Push notifications and follow steps here: https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#push-notifications-troubleshooting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a Push Notification Certificate and upload it into your Parse App's Push settings. In order to do that you should request the certificate in Apple Developer Member Center.